# Jquery slider javascript help required, thumbnails not in correct order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using wow slider and there is some issue, which causes the bullets, which onhover show thumbs of images and point to that image in sequence onClick. Howeverver at no. 13 and afterwards images are not in sync (as shown on bullet hover/onMouseover), but click on bullet in slideshow points to correct image.

I tweaked some css but in vain..is it possible to do it by editing Script.js or style.css, Please somebody help to resolve this.

[Please see the code in action here](http://kapilind.sitesled.com/wow/index.htm).

Thanks in Adv,

Anita

[PS: I am using IE7.0 as browser.]

Comment: They seem to be in the correct order in Chromium 11, Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: @Anita, didn't understand where is the problem??

Comment: @diEcho In IE7 on mouseover at the bullet 13 (see title) the thumb preview and onclick image are not in sync.

Comment: @Anita, sync bole to...note same which is shown on thumb and img box? right

Comment: @Anita working fine here

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be in working order with FF 4 for Mac.

The issue you are having could be a result of IE7's difficulty with `:hover`

The bullets are in `<DIV class=ws_bullets>` which has a `:hover` action associated with it in the stylesheet, and my guess is that's what is causing you problems in IE7.

Do all of the demos on WOWslider.com function properly on your machine in IE7?

Comment: . Yes all work okay via wowslider.com, the only difference I see is  size of my image area and the number of images used. It works good till 10 images in IE7

Comment: Hover action should work for anchor <a> elements in IE (most versions) but issues can be with div or other elements in HTML. The ws_bullet div is referenced in CSS wrt anchor<a> tags hover action.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps the script does some form of ordering and is sequencing the number as "1, 10, 11, 12, 13 ... 2, 3, 4" instead of the correct order. Try using 2-digit number throughout and see if that makes any difference i.e. "01, 02, 03" instead of "1, 2, 3"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: it has some internal coding in the script which causes it, since it was demo version of wow slider. It wasn't displaying thumbs beyond 11/12 and used credits in b/w to make it work correctly.